# Object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, summarization

I am trying to use the code that is on this [link](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/blob/master/ipynb/Chapter%205%20-%20Mining%20Web%20Pages.ipynb)... see example 6.

So this is the code:

```
import json
import nltk
import numpy

BLOG_DATA = "resources/ch05-webpages/feed.json"

N = 100  # Number of words to consider
CLUSTER_THRESHOLD = 5  # Distance between words to consider
TOP_SENTENCES = 5  # Number of sentences to return for a "top n" summary

# Approach taken from "The Automatic Creation of Literature Abstracts" by H.P. Luhn

def _score_sentences(sentences, important_words):
    scores = []
    sentence_idx = -1

for s in [nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(s) for s in sentences]:

    sentence_idx += 1
    word_idx = []

    # For each word in the word list...
    for w in important_words:
        try:
            # Compute an index for where any important words occur in the sentence.

            word_idx.append(s.index(w))
        except ValueError, e: # w not in this particular sentence
            pass

    word_idx.sort()

    # It is possible that some sentences may not contain any important words at all.
    if len(word_idx)== 0: continue

    # Using the word index, compute clusters by using a max distance threshold
    # for any two consecutive words.

    clusters = []
    cluster = [word_idx[0]]
    i = 1
    while i < len(word_idx):
        if word_idx[i] - word_idx[i - 1] < CLUSTER_THRESHOLD:
            cluster.append(word_idx[i])
        else:
            clusters.append(cluster[:])
            cluster = [word_idx[i]]
        i += 1
    clusters.append(cluster)

    # Score each cluster. The max score for any given cluster is the score 
    # for the sentence.

    max_cluster_score = 0
    for c in clusters:
        significant_words_in_cluster = len(c)
        total_words_in_cluster = c[-1] - c[0] + 1
        score = 1.0 * significant_words_in_cluster \
            * significant_words_in_cluster / total_words_in_cluster

        if score > max_cluster_score:
            max_cluster_score = score

    scores.append((sentence_idx, score))

return scores

def summarize(txt):
   sentences = [s for s in nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(txt)]
   normalized_sentences = [s.lower() for s in sentences]

   words = [w.lower() for sentence in normalized_sentences for w in
         nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)]

   fdist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

   top_n_words = [w[0] for w in fdist.items() 
        if w[0] not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')][:N]

   scored_sentences = _score_sentences(normalized_sentences, top_n_words)

 # Summarization Approach 1:
 # Filter out nonsignificant sentences by using the average score plus a
 # fraction of the std dev as a filter

avg = numpy.mean([s[1] for s in scored_sentences])
std = numpy.std([s[1] for s in scored_sentences])
mean_scored = [(sent_idx, score) for (sent_idx, score) in scored_sentences
               if score > avg + 0.5 * std]

# Summarization Approach 2:
# Another approach would be to return only the top N ranked sentences

top_n_scored = sorted(scored_sentences, key=lambda s: s[1])[-TOP_SENTENCES:]
top_n_scored = sorted(top_n_scored, key=lambda s: s[0])

# Decorate the post object with summaries

return dict(top_n_summary=[sentences[idx] for (idx, score) in top_n_scored],
            mean_scored_summary=[sentences[idx] for (idx, score) in mean_scored])

blog_data = json.loads(open(BLOG_DATA).read())

for post in blog_data:

   post.update(summarize(post['content']))

   print post['title']
   print '=' * len(post['title'])
   print
   print 'Top N Summary'
   print '-------------'
   print ' '.join(post['top_n_summary'])
   print
   print 'Mean Scored Summary'
   print '-------------------'
   print ' '.join(post['mean_scored_summary'])
   print
```

But when I run it it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jetonp/PycharmProjects/Summeriza/blogs_and_nlp__summarize.py", line 117, in <module>
    post.update(summarize(post['content']))
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'update'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please paste the entire code you are using.

Comment: No need to scream, thanks.

Comment: Did you define `blog_data` anywhere? Remember, Python identifiers are case sensitive. In the example you linked, `blog_data` and `BLOG_DATA` are different variables.

Comment: We need to see what the variable blog_data is. update is a method that dictionaries have. In the blog, blog_data contains a dictionary that was created by loading the blog's json using the json.loads method.

Comment: Yeah I know that they are sensitive, first 
BLOG_DATA = "resources/ch05-webpages/feed.json" and then blog_data = json.loads(open(BLOG_DATA).read())

Comment: BLOG_DATA = "resources/ch05-webpages/feed.json" Are you sure that this is the correct path for feed.json? I'd recommend debugging with the line `for line in open(BLOG_DATA): print line`

Comment: @nfazzio actually I changed that line of code to BLOG_DATA = "feed.json" since I have the JSON file in same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In the example that you are working off of, the summarize method returns a dictionary. Your summarize method does not return anything, due to improper indentation.  For part of it, there is just three spaces, and for part of it there were no spaces. The standard indentation in python is four spaces. Summarize should look like this:

```
def summarize(txt):
    sentences = [s for s in nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(txt)]
    normalized_sentences = [s.lower() for s in sentences]

    words = [w.lower() for sentence in normalized_sentences for w in
          nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)]

    fdist = nltk.FreqDist(words)

    top_n_words = [w[0] for w in fdist.items() 
        if w[0] not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')][:N]

    scored_sentences = _score_sentences(normalized_sentences, top_n_words)

     # Summarization Approach 1:
     # Filter out nonsignificant sentences by using the average score plus a
     # fraction of the std dev as a filter

    avg = numpy.mean([s[1] for s in scored_sentences])
    std = numpy.std([s[1] for s in scored_sentences])
    mean_scored = [(sent_idx, score) for (sent_idx, score) in scored_sentences
                   if score > avg + 0.5 * std]

    # Summarization Approach 2:
    # Another approach would be to return only the top N ranked sentences

    top_n_scored = sorted(scored_sentences, key=lambda s: s[1])[-TOP_SENTENCES:]
    top_n_scored = sorted(top_n_scored, key=lambda s: s[0])

    # Decorate the post object with summaries

    return dict(top_n_summary=[sentences[idx] for (idx, score) in top_n_scored],
                mean_scored_summary=[sentences[idx] for (idx, score) in mean_scored])
```

Comment: What is happens if you debug within the for loop with a print statement `print type(summarize(post['content']))`. If your summarize method is working properly, it should be a `dict`.

Comment: From debugging it seems "dict" but I don't know what is the problem, anyway thnx I appreciate it.

Comment: Are you scraping from the Oreilly site like in the example? This works for me when I use the data scraped from the site in ex4.